# jquery scrollTop with animation

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I'm trying to place a simple "scroll to top" button at the bottom of my page that uses a smooth scroll to the top.  Everything I've read says this should be a simple matter of using a "animate({scrollTop})" script.  However, it always jumps directly to the top for me, skipping the scroll animation.

The script:

```
$('#jump').click(function(){
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0px
    }, 600);
});
```

and the html tag (style tags included just in case):

```
<a href="#" id="jump" style="position:absolute; bottom:10px; right:10px">scroll to top</a>
```

Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating an abridged version of the same problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/5V5Tf/

This seems like a straightforward problem... figure I'm just being absentminded and missing something obvious.

Thanks

Comment: `0px` is not a valid JavaScript literal. Change it to `'0px'` (quoted) or just `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your link still has an `href` in it, because of that it is behaving like a normal link. Remove the `href="#"` in your markup and you should be golden. Otherwise, you would need to call `preventDefault()` on the event generated by clicking the anchor.

Edit: here is a [modified version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dy5w3/) with it working.

Answer (score 0):

Works, when you work with **body** at the *onclick-event*: http://jsfiddle.net/TPwpK/

```
$('#jump').click(function(){
    $('body').animate({'scrollTop': '0'}, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5V5Tf/1/).

changed `$('.iframe')` to `$('body')`
and you need to `preventDefault()` the event